# How to use Ratchet websocket inside CakePHP shell

Tags: php, cakephp, websocket, ratchet

I want to create a Websocket and need to access CakePHP ORM from this one.
I'm using Ratchet Websocket with the following code:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

    // Make sure composer dependencies have been installed
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * chat.php
 * Send any incoming messages to all connected clients (except sender)
 */
class MyChat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from != $client) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

To run the code:

```
$app = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
$app->route('/chat', new MyChat);
$app->route('/echo', new Ratchet\Server\EchoServer, array('*'));
$app->run();
```

I need to do two things:

1. I need to access CakePHP ORM inside MyChat class.
2. I need to start that class in a CakePHP task shell.

The second one is quite easy, but the first one I don't know how to init ORM classes to throw queries inside MyChat class.

Comment: How to use in cakephp 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it passing itself to MyChat constructor like:

```
$app->route('/chat', new MyChat($this));
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the ORM you could instatiate the Model classes like any other class and make queries with them or whatever you need.

Edit

If you're going to use the cake shell you just need to import your models with App::uses or even better you could use the 'uses' array variable. More information in the docs book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

Comment: But, I don't know what classes should be included before that.